# Is it possible to search for an address (rather than a transaction ID) in the bitcoin mempool?

Tags: address, mempool, mempool.space

Is it possible to search *pending* bitcoin transactions by their "to" address?

I looked at several mempool navigator/explorer type services and they all seem to allow searching by transaction ID but not to/from address?  (e.g. https://mempool.space/)

Why is this? Are the to/from addresses not visible on pending transactions? (I assume they are visible)

If the addresses are visible on pending transactions why do mempool search tools not allow searching by address?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible. Block explorers such as mempool.space allow you to search by address, and they will show you all transactions involving that address, including unconfirmed ones.